# Want to create spaces in between graph lines with step function MatPlotLib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was playing around in python and I wanted to create a step graph function that takes in a two-dimensional list with each list consisting of 1s and 0s, and graphs each list on a separate line, similar to this:
[clocking graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ud8kb.png) 
[image]

When I run my code it looks like this: [Code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXK1g.png)
[image]

It can be a bit hard to read, especially when using a much bigger list. I want to create spaces in between the graph lines to make it more readable. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# supress warning message
import warnings; warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
# extension libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


bits = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]

for i in range(len(bits)):
    data = np.repeat(bits[i], 2)
    t = 0.5 * np.arange(len(data))

    plt.hold(True)
    plt.step(t, data + i, linewidth=1.5, where='post', color='g')

    plt.ylim([-1, 10])

    # Labels the graphs with binary sequence
    for tbit, bit in enumerate(bits[i]):
        plt.text(tbit + 0.2, i, str(bit), fontsize=12, color='g')

    # removes the built in graph axes and prints line every interation
    plt.gca().axis('off')


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to increase the vertical spacing of each of your lines by increasing the y-value. To make it easy, I simply multiplied `i` by 2 to space your lines a little further apart. If you want more control over the location of the lines, you could have a list of y-values and iterate over that instead.

```
bits = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]]

for i in range(len(bits)):
    data = np.repeat(bits[i], 2)
    t = 0.5 * np.arange(len(data))

    plt.hold(True)
    plt.step(t, data + i*2, linewidth=1.5, where='post', color='g')
    #                 ^^^^^^

    plt.ylim([-1, 10])

    # Labels the graphs with binary sequence
    for tbit, bit in enumerate(bits[i]):
        plt.text(tbit + 0.2, 0.25+i*2, str(bit), fontsize=12, color='g')
    #                        ^^^^^^^^^

    # removes the built in graph axes and prints line every interation
    plt.gca().axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image]